# NSCollectionView for Cocoa-Touch (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, nscollectionview

Is was starting to implement one but was wondering if somebody knows about an already existing NSCollectionView like class for cocoa touch.

Comment: What aspect of NSCollectionView do you want to replicate?  UITableView + custom cells gives you almost everything + more?  Curious.

Comment: @Jeff as you see in the AQGridView description such a component makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alan Quatermain was nice enough to make such a view, called [AQGridView](http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/528737778/aqgridview-lives-for-my-ipad-dev-camp-hackathon)

Comment: How do you handle grid cell selection? The "documentation" is pretty weak in explaining how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean multiple item selection with "grid cell selection"?

Comment: Another alternative is the KKGridView, not sure which one is really superior though (if any of the two): https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView